# Use TokenAuthentication AND SocialAuthentication from AllAuth

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I've created a new Django Rest API thanks to Django Rest Framework and I want to use two type of authentication : TokenAuthentication AND SocialAuthentication with two providers Facebook and Google.

Token authentication is success (with this syntax : `Authorization: Token <token>`. However, I can't get it to work with the SocialAuthentication. When I get the access_token from my POST in GoogleSocialLoginView, I can't use it to login in my others API call headers (I use an authenticated permissions for others CRUD calls). My syntax for social authentication is :

`Authorization : Bearer <token>`

So the users are registered successfully in database, but they can't authenticated us to the API after.

This is a part of my settings.py

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
]

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_swagger',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    "dj_rest_auth",
    'dj_rest_auth.registration',
    'allauth', 
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    # Local apps we created
    'api',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'thetiptop.urls'
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'api.Users'
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS':'rest_framework.schemas.coreapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "LOGIN_SERIALIZER": "api.serializers.CustomLoginSerializer",
}

REST_USE_JWT = True
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True
OLD_PASSWORD_FIELD_ENABLED = True
SITE_ID = 2
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = { 
    'google': { 
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' }
    },
    'facebook': { 
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'INIT_PARAMS': {'cookie': True},
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v13.0'
    }
}
```

My url.py file list this URL :

```
    path('auth/login/', obtain_auth_token, name='login'),
    path('auth/', include('dj_rest_auth.urls')), 
    path('auth/registration/', include('dj_rest_auth.registration.urls')),
    path('auth/facebook/', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
    path('auth/google/', GoogleLogin.as_view(), name='google_login'),
    path('accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),
```

And finally, the GoogleLogin and FacebookLogin are the same as :

```
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.google.views import GoogleOAuth2Adapter
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.oauth2.client import OAuth2Client

class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter

class GoogleLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = GoogleOAuth2Adapter
    client_class = OAuth2Client
```

Finally, I use this type of authentication for others CRUD calls :

```
from rest_framework import permissions

permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Do you know a solution to use a token authentication and a allauth social authentication in the same User class ?

PS: I'm consuming the API from an Angular app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's important to keep in mind that there is a difference between the default authentication system in Django and the authentication system for DRF. In your DRF configuration, you have only specified two classes: `rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication` and `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication`. The `SessionAuthentication` is the only one that is compatible with the default Django session authentication backend (but that may not be what you want anyhow).

As [covered in the DRF API guide](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) if you are using session-based authentication, you must include a CSRF token for authenticated requests:

> If you're using an AJAX-style API with SessionAuthentication, you'll need to make sure you include a valid CSRF token for any "unsafe" HTTP method calls, such as PUT, PATCH, POST or DELETE requests. [...]
> CSRF validation in REST framework works slightly differently from standard Django due to the need to support both session and non-session based authentication to the same views. This means that only authenticated requests require CSRF tokens, and anonymous requests may be sent without CSRF tokens.

So, if you are using a user's session (assuming you've authenticated the user's session previously) you will need to pass CSRF tokens when calling the DRF API in addition to the session cookie.

---

You may want to consider using an authentication method that works directly with DRF such as [one recommended in the DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#drf-social-oauth2) like `drf-social-oauth2`. Then add it to your DRF authentication classes directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I follow your advice and It's worked for a part of the Authentication. However, when I use the drf_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication as authentication class, I have this error : 
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'social' is not a registered namespace

Do you encounter this error in the past ?

Comment: Glad to hear that works @Gati -- as far as the other error, make sure you've registered your installed apps routes in urls.py and remove references to any installed apps you may have removed -- if the original question is answered, please consider accepting it. If you have additional issues you can't resolve, consider raising a separate question in order to get the best help for that issue.